# Run Angular6 app with cli 1.7, get error Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to run Angular6 project with cli 1.7? My current version are

--

Angular CLI: 1.7.4

Node: 10.8.0

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 6.1.8

--

get this error message:

```
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null

at Class.run (C:\my-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:51:63)
at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (C:\my-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

For some reason the deploy environment doesn't support node newer than 7 therefore not support angular-cli 6. But my app is build with angular 6. So I'm trying to find if there is any way to build angular app with angular-cli 1.7? Must angular 6 apps run with angular-cli 6 and node newer than 7? In other words, can I run angular 6 app without updating cli to 6?

Comment: Do you have the call stack for the error? Usually it will provide line numbers.

Comment: when you use angular ng build it uses the local version of angular-cli so you can have 6 installed globally and manually install 1.7.x in your local project.   did you do ng update ? perhaps angular didn't finish updating to 6? i know when i went from 5 to 6 it wasn't happy with my config / build until everything got correctly updated.

Comment: @Zuriel is correct. It looks like your app has not been fully updated you. With Angular 6 the major version of the Angular CLI is in sync. For example, Angular 6.1.8 should match up with the the Angular CLI 6.X.X (Presumably Angular CLI 6.2.3). Just wait till you have to update all of the rxjs imports :)

Comment: @Rod I didn't mean to update cli to 6 because I was trying to build an angular 6 app with cli 1.7. Is there any way to do this or must I update cli to 6 to run an angular 6 app?

Comment: @Zuriel When you update 5 to 6, do you also update both local and global cli to 6?

Comment: @Robin You cannot build an Angular 6 app with an Angular 5 CLI. You will have to update your Angular CLI before you can build your Angular 6 project.